# What module bests fits my application?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi

I am trying to pick a wifi module that would fit what I am trying to accomplish. My application is pretty basic: I have an application on a IPad/tablet that communicates over wifi to my product. Basically it is just a wireless wire not connected to a router or anything else, just direct communication to my end product.

I've been looking at a CCC3120MOD which seems to fit but it looks to have a lot more then what I want compared to what I am using it for.

First do you think i should use WIFI at all, sinc I am using it for is a direct connection?
Should i maybe go with a bluetooth module using SPP instead?

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Go with WiFi. Easy to get working, lots of software tools available (at least on a PC), and if your application expands you're not limited. The ESP8266 based modules are easy to use and really cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each choose of protocol have to fit onto constrants and requirements. Some protocol vs another protocol is always a tradeoff.

From your post I know what you need interoperability with tablets (smartphones). In fact you may use only Bluetooth Classic, Bluetooth Smart, WiFi.

First you need to decide:

1. Which bandwidth your need?
2. Which power budget you have?
3. Which protocol may be more fittable in your case?
4. Computational requirements (where is HCI is placed, how interract with module/chip) and code complexity?
5. Suitable pricing for each chip?

When you will ask for all question you may choose approtiate protocol.

For helping you I described main characteristics of each protocol.

Bluetooth classic (you can use SPP for it):

1. Typical current up to 50 mA
2. Typical bandwidth up to 1000 kbps (really up to 800)
3. Suitable for simple case, remote control cases, audio streaming, raw data streaming from device.
4. Low computational requirements.
5. Low pricing.

Bluetooth Smart (aka Bluetooth Low Energy):

1. Typical current up to 8 mA;
2. Typical bandwidth 250 kbps (4.0), 1000 kbps (5.0)
3. Suitable for metering, smart devices, remote control, as replacement of a display, and cases for low power budget
4. Low computational requirements.
5. The lowest pricing.

WiFi:

1. Typical current up to 200 mA;
2. Typical bandwidth up to 300 mbps;
3. Suitable for video and audio streaming, cases with high payload, cases with SOHO devices intergration (mainly routers).
4. Middle computational requirements.
5. Middle pricing.

Comment: That really helped thanks for taking the time to write that out.It looks like bluetooth classic will work perfect for what i have right? Here are my specs bandwidth is 30 kilo.byte/second max,power is 3400mAh battery,HCI isnt that high all the device is doing is taking data it gets from the tablet and sending it onto a spi line to another IC on the board very small computations if any,budget pricing isnt a huge factor in this project.

Comment: @user155600 Blutooth classic fits in your application. By the way with such small speed you may look at BLE

Comment: yes BLE for my situation would be better,which iam dealing with making a program on ios to communicate with my device. and getting access to classic mode is more work but BLE is more a plug-n-play on ios.Just a fyi if you want BT classic on IOS you need to be a MFI registered developer and usually the chip manufacturer will provide a stack once you provide a MFI license number to them.